# MyStringStack c++ can't call method of my class

Tags: c++, stack, constants

I have been trying to implement Stack that holds objects of MyString class (it is exercise from one of the books). I managed to push those objects to container, but when I want to call function void print() I get an error:

*error: passing 'const MyString' as 'this' argument of 'void MyString::print()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
       cp->print();*

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class MyString
{
    string a;
public:
    MyString(string aa) : a(aa)
    {

    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

class StringStack {
  static const int size = 100;
  const MyString* stack[size];
  int index;
public:
  StringStack();
  void push(const MyString* s);     // does this have to be const?
  const MyString* pop();    // does this have to be const?
};

StringStack::StringStack() : index(0) {
  memset(stack, 0, size * sizeof(MyString*));
}

void StringStack::push(const MyString* s) {
  if(index < size)
    stack[index++] = s;
}

const MyString* StringStack::pop() {
  if(index > 0) {
    const MyString* rv = stack[--index];
    stack[index] = 0;
    return rv;
  }
  return 0;
}

MyString s0("pralines & cream");
MyString s1("fudge ripple");
MyString s2("jamocha almond fudge");
MyString s3("wild mountain blackberry");
MyString s4("raspberry sorbet");
MyString s5("lemon swirl");
MyString s6("rocky road");
MyString s7("deep chocolate fudge");

MyString iceCream[] = {s0,s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7};
const int iCsz =
  sizeof iceCream / sizeof *iceCream;

int main() {
  StringStack ss;
  for(int i = 0; i < iCsz; i++)
    ss.push(&iceCream[i]);
  const MyString* cp;
  while((cp = ss.pop()) != 0)
  {
      cout << (long)cp << endl;
      // cp->print();    // won't work
  }
} ///:~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either:

1. make `void MyString::print()` const, which seems to be reasonable.

or :

2. make `const MyString* pop();` to return non const pointers.

I dont think that `StringStack` should store pointers to const objects. If you plan to never modify `MyString` objects from your stack, then keep them internally as `const`. The choice depends on your requirements.

Comment: 1. When I make this method const, I get the same error 2. When I erase const from implementation, program compiles but it crashes after I run it

Comment: @dodoptak `void print() const` - should compile

Comment: Thank you. What is the difference between `void const print()` and `void print() const`?

Comment: @dodoptak in `void const print()` you say you want `print()` to return constant void, which makes no sense because `void print()' should not return anything. Actually Visual Studio does not give error for that.